# jersey filter throwing exception on Tomcat

Tags: java, rest, maven, tomcat, jersey

I'm trying to implement rest token security between my clients and webserver. I implemented a filter to get the http authentiction header and check if the client is valid. Although, for some reason my Tomcat is throwing an exception end starts.

My implementation of the filter is:

```
import java.security.Principal;

    import javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException;
    import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
    import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext;
    import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
    import javax.annotation.Priority;
    import javax.ws.rs.Priorities;


        @Secured
        @Provider
        @Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
        public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

            @Override
            public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {...}
```

The exception I get from Tomcat is:

```
 br 05, 2017 12:09:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [JAX-RS Servlet] in context with path [/My_App] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
        at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:120)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:669)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
```

I have thim POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SamuraiForge</groupId>
  <artifactId>0</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.snaq</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbpool</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jettison/jettison -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lmax/disruptor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
            <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.24</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.24</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.24</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.3</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-servlet -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-json -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1-m05</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-jaxrs -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Any particular reason you replaced `javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1` with `javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.1-m05`? That would be my guess as to the cause of your problem.

Comment: `UriBuilder.uri(String)` is listed as **Since: 2.0**. `jersey-server-1.19.3.jar` provides a version 1.1 implementation of `UriBuilder`. In short, `com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.19.3` is not compatible with any version 2.x of `javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api`.

Comment: Although com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.19. is the last version o jersey. So how can I solve the problem? I nee to use @NameBinding.

Comment: It is not. If you check the Maven Repository for [`com.sun.jersey:jersey-server`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server), you'll see new name of [`org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server), where latest version is `2.26-b03`, and it depends on `javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.1-m05`, like you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Andreas, remove

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1-m05</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the cause of the error. But you seems to be trying to actually use it. The `ContainerRequestFilter` you are using, is something that is JAX-RS 2.0, but you are using Jersey 1.x, which is JAX-RS 1.x. You can't use some of the JAX-RS 2 APIs in JAX-RS 1.x. This includes the `ContainerRequestFilter`.

Jersey 1.x has a filter [`ContainerRequestFilter`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.18/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html), but the API is little different. You can use this with Jersey 1.x, but it doesn't have some of the features that the JAX-RS `ContainerRequestFilter` has. For instance there is no such concept of `SecurityContext` with the Jersey filter. So you will be able to do `setSecurityContext(new YouSecurityContext())`. This may be a problem for you, since it looks like this is what you are using the filter for. You will need to figure some other way to do it. Otherwise, you will need to make the complete switch to Jersey 2.x, where you can use JAX-RS 2